# How to remove semicolon form the json object using php

Tags: php, json, regex

How can i remove semicolon from the end of the json object.

**Json Object**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "clear": "test",
    "fsssf": "2017-09-18 04:13:00",
    "tex": "asfasdfasdf",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "clear": "test",
    "fsssf": "2017-09-18 04:13:00",
    "tex": "asfasdfasdf",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
}];
```

I have tried with `rtrim`, `substr`, `stropt` and all are not working.

I need to replace this with ',' to use with datatable api

Comment: How do you get this json? Where does this semicolon come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use rtrim

```
<?php

$a = ' [{
    "id": 1,
    "clear": "test",
    "fsssf": "2017-09-18 04:13:00",
    "tex": "asfasdfasdf",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
 }, {
    "id": 2,
    "clear": "test",
    "fsssf": "2017-09-18 04:13:00",
    "tex": "asfasdfasdf",
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": null
 }];';


 $a= rtrim($a, ';').',';

 print_r($a);

 ?>
```

working example https://ideone.com/qkcSpL

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you want to remove or replace the semicolon. I tried to answer both ways.

**Remove**

```
   <?php
    $lastCharRemoved = substr("abcdef", -1); 
    ?>
```

The Code above gives gives back "abcde".

```
<?php
    $json = substr($json, -1); 
?>
```

So this would give your JSON back with the semicolon removed.

**Replace**

But if you want to replace the semicolon:

```
<?php
echo str_replace("world","Peter","Hello world!");
?>
```

The above gives back "Hello Peter".

```
<?php
echo str_replace(";",",",$json);
?>
```

This would replace the ";" with ","

*Greetings and happy coding!*

Comment: Its not working,these methods works fine with string not json